# What versioning workflow is recommended for a Cookiecutter Django project?

Tags: cookiecutter-django

I've seen that `__version__` lives inside `project_slug/__init__.py`, so my question is when I'm updating a version I should both edit this file and git tag with the new version or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would update `__version__` manually and then git tag.

If you wanted to do both in a single command, you could use bumpversion:
https://github.com/peritus/bumpversion